# Angular.io (SystemJS) THREE is not defined ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I started to use three.js in angular.io and have this error:

```
(index):18 Error: (SystemJS) THREE is not defined
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js:16:1)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js:1044:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js:1045:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/three-basis/three-camera-orbit-control.component.js
```

My imports and component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CameraProvider} from './camera-provider.service';
import 'threejs/controls/OrbitControls';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three';

@Component({selector: 'three-camera-orbit-control', template: ''})
export class ThreeCameraOrbitControlComponent {

    constructor(private cameraProvider: CameraProvider) {
        let camera = this.cameraProvider.getCamera();
        let controls = new OrbitControls(camera);
        controls.addEventListener('change', () => {});
    }

}
```

If I add this `var THREE = require("three");` in OrbitControls.js in my node_modules/three, error gones and all is ok. I'm not good in js yet, can please some one help me, how to do it wright way? Thanks.

Comment: Had workaround as adding new module three-orbitcontrol-ts, by dont like this, want to understand problem on js/angular level.

Answer (score -2):

See working example of using Angular + Three.js including OrbitControls and ColladaLoader: https://github.com/makimenko/angular-three-examples

Currently, Three.js examples are not included into a module and use them in Angular typescript code could be a little bit tricky. One of solution/workaround could be:

Firstly, include dependencies:

```
three
@types/three
```

Secondly, import in component:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import "./js/EnableThreeExamples";
import "three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls";
import "three/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader";
```

Then use it in code:

```
this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera);
this.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
this.controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
```

Hope this could help you to start

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)